# smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send a  mail from python, but it shows

> smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

Here is my code:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def send_email(email):
    from_email="mine@gmail.com"
    from_password="xxxxx"
    to_email=email

    subject="Data"
    message = "Hey there!!"

    msg=MIMEText(message,'html')
    msg['Subject']=subject
    msg['To']=to_email
    msg['From']=from_email

    gmail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    gmail.connect('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    gmail.ehlo()
    gmail.starttls()
    gmail.login(from_email,from_password)


    gmail.sendmail(from_email,to_email,msg.as_string())
    gmail.quit()
```

I've checked the less secure apps option in gmail so it should work fine but its not working. I've tried other suggestions like remove `starttls()` command but nothing is working.
My question is not answered in any of the similar posts, so do look at it before marking it as duplicate.

Comment: It is better to include your research about the related post and explaining why they don't meet your requirement. That is enough to avoid duplicate confusions. Welcome to Stack-overflow.

Comment: I thought of doing so but it would take a lot of time then before anyone actually answers correctly.

Comment: It is good practice to do so, one or 2 sentences to show you have done some searching before putting forward a question and let people understands why it is not a duplicate right away.